# Why is boost::locale::to_title not returning the expected output?

Tags: c++, string, boost, title-case, boost-locale

So I've already found [How to capitalize a word in a C++ string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369910/how-to-capitalize-a-word-in-a-c-string) , but I've tried similar code as has been suggested, including what's provided in the examples for Boost::locale. I'll also include what my code is currently and what the expected and real output are. So I'm trying to understand why I'm not getting the expected output.

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/case_conv.hpp>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost::locale;

    generator gen;
    auto loc = gen("");
    locale::global(loc);
    cout.imbue(loc);

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    cout << to_upper("hello!") << " " << boost::to_upper_copy("hello!"s) << endl;
    cout << to_lower("HELLO!") << " " << boost::to_lower_copy("HELLO!"s) << endl;
    cout << to_title("hELLO!") << endl;
    cout << fold_case("HELLO!") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Expected Output

```
HELLO! HELLO!
hello! hello!
Hello!
hello!
```

### Real Output

```
HELLO! HELLO!
hello! hello!
hELLO!
hello!
```

### Additional Information

- OS: Windows 10 Home 64-bit
- Compiler: Microsoft Visual Studio 15.8.0
- Platform: x64
- Non-default Compilation Options: `/std:c++latest`
- BOOST_VERSION: 106700

### EDIT #1

It seems that the Boost that is installed by vcpkg doesn't get compiled
with ICU, which is apparently required for `boost::locale::to_title` to
function correctly.

Comment: did you build boost with ICU support? It seems `to_title` is supported only for ICU

Comment: Works for me on Linux, GCC 7, Boost 1.67, ICU

Comment: @miradham The boost I was using was automatically built by vcpkg, so I have no idea, but that seems likely.

Comment: It looks like I can install the ICU based versions of boost libraries using vcpkg. Now I just have to wait at least a couple hours, for boost to be completely recompiled again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**vcpkg** (https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg) by default installs Boost without depending on ICU for the Boost::locale and Boost::regex libraries.

So, instead of installing those like this:

```
vcpkg install boost-locale:x64-windows boost-regex:x64-windows
```

I had to do the following:

```
vcpkg install boost-locale[icu]:x64-windows boost-regex[icu]:x64-windows
```

This automatically fetches and builds the ICU library, and (since I had already installed Boost without ICU) it automatically rebuilt *all* of the Boost libraries.

I wish the Boost documentation for those libraries made it clear that you needed ICU to use the functionality that requires it.

Answer (score 0):

`title_case` is handled only for [ICU](https://github.com/boostorg/locale/blob/develop/src/icu/conversion.cpp) as per source code of [boost locale](https://github.com/boostorg/locale), while for other platforms like for ex [win32](https://github.com/boostorg/locale/blob/develop/src/win32/converter.cpp) it returns input value as it is.

So in order to use `to_title` function you have to make sure to use boost locale for ICU

```
virtual string_type convert(converter_base::conversion_type how,char_type const *begin,char_type const *end,int flags = 0) const 
{
    icu_std_converter<char_type> cvt(encoding_);
    icu::UnicodeString str=cvt.icu(begin,end);
    switch(how) {
        ...
        case converter_base::title_case:
            str.toTitle(0,locale_);
            break;
        case converter_base::case_folding:
            str.foldCase();
            break;
        default:
            ;
    }
    return cvt.std(str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, I only accepted my answer because it had more to do with my specific use case.